# Facebook SDK4.0 [FBSDKInternalUtility isFacebookAppInstalled]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: ios, facebook

Code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"result:%@", result);

             if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, birthday, picture"}]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      if (!error) {
                          NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);


                      }
                  }];
             }
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

I used above code for facebook login integration.It gives expection as "+[FBSDKInternalUtility isFacebookAppInstalled]: unrecognized selector sent to class".Where i went wrong?any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I just tested your code on test data and it works without a problem, did you make sure to import the FBSDKLoginKit module?

Comment: perhaps import the module like this in your viewcontroller: @import FBSDKLoginKit;

Comment: yes. it is imported.let me delete and add it again..

Comment: that's strange, it's working without an issue for me, are you using a production build app to test this? or are you using the "fake users" provided by Facebook? Is your app on Facebook or still in dev mode where you can only use test users?

Comment: issue with my xcode. me too tried in another in system,it is working fine,thanks for your help..